# Distribution of Queue Length at Next Arrival

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing-theory, geometric-probability, stationary-processes

I'm trying to figure out the following:

Suppose that an $M/M/1$ is at stationarity (arrival rate $\lambda$, service rate $\mu$).

Suppose that $B$ is the next person to arrive in the queue.

What is the distribution of the number of people in the queue when $B$ arrives?

Comment: Poisson Arrivals See Time Averages (PASTA) is the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617146/arrival-distribution-of-m-m-1-queue/3632392#3632392

Answer (score 1):

Assuming balance conditions exist ($\mu>\lambda$), just use them

Let $\pi_i$ be the probability of being in state $i$

We have the following system then:

$\pi_1 =\pi_0 (\lambda/\mu) , ..., \pi_i=\pi_0(\lambda/\mu)^i$

Sum of the probabilities of all of the states should be 1

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \pi_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \pi_0(\lambda/\mu)^i = \pi_0 1/(1-(\lambda/\mu))=1$ Then $\pi_0=1-(\lambda/\mu)$

You are interested in expected number of jobs in the system (If you are not convinced please search Poisson Arrivals See Time Averages, PASTA)

Anyway $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\pi_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\pi_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i\pi_0(\lambda / \mu)^i=\pi_0(\lambda / \mu)\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(\lambda / \mu)^{i-1}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(\lambda / \mu)^{i-1}$ is the derivative of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\lambda / \mu)^{i}$ wrt $(\lambda / \mu)$

From here you can conclude

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(\lambda / \mu)^{i-1}=1/(1-(\lambda / \mu))^2$

So expected number of jobs $E=\pi_0(\lambda / \mu)/(1-(\lambda / \mu))^2=(1-(\lambda / \mu))(\lambda / \mu)/(1-(\lambda / \mu))^2=(\lambda / \mu)/(1-(\lambda / \mu))=\lambda/(\mu-\lambda)$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! But this isn't exactly what I'm interested in: I'm interested in the distribution of the number of people in the queue at the time of the next arrival. That is, the queue reaches stationarity and then we wait until the next arrival, then what is the distribution of the number of people in the queue? I think it will be geometric with parameter greater than $1 - (\lambda / \mu)$...

Comment: Stationary distribution terms are given as $\pi_i$. If you are talking about a conditional observation (sorry I believe there is something lost between your intentions and my comprehension) just use the stationary distribution and Bayes'

Comment: Yeah that's incorrect

Comment: I really recommend you to check PASTA property, but I will make an edit to my post later today.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the distribution of the people in the queue when $B$ arrives will be $X_{t}-N_{t}$, where $X_{t} \sim \pi$ (the distribution at stationarity), $N_{t} \sim Pois(\mu A_{t})$ and $A_{t}\sim Exp(\lambda) $.

Intuitively, this can be thought of as the number of people in the queue at stationarity ($X_{t}$) minus the number of people who leave the queue before $B$ arrives ($N_{t})$ which will take a time $A_{t}$.